# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word OMath

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-interop

this is my first question on StackOverflow, so have patience :D

I'm actually trying to generate .docx files from .txt files throught Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word lib in Visual Studio Environment (I'm coding in C#).

Those Word files are meant to be exercices for children with specific help (colors, size, etc...).

Some of the txt files contains equations that I would like to recreate on Word with the specifi tool "OMath" (that, if I understood, will be used to create those "equation" boxes).

At that time, I didn't succeeded in generating more than 1 box at a time. For example, if a txt has 2 or more equations, all of them are created in the same equation box but not separately.

I have tried a code like that :

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

...

Word.Application wapp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document wdoc = wapp.Documents.Add();

...

wpara = wdoc.Paragraphs.Add();
e.ElementAspect.setFormat(ref wpara); // set wpara format (color, font ...)
Word.Range test1 = wapp.Selection.Range;
test1.Text = e.Content;
test1 = wpara.Range.OMaths.Add(test1);
Word.OMath equation = test1.OMaths[1];
equation.BuildUp();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use `wapp.Selection` object. `Selection` is used for current cursor/user location in document (in short) - [Selection interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.aspx)

Secondly, using `wpara = wdoc.Paragraphs.Add()` from what I have tested, gives you paragraph in current selection.

This code (as you encountered) will overwrite in each iteration prevoius equation.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    var para = oDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
    var paraRange = para.Range;
    paraRange.Text = "x^2 + " + i + " = y";     
}
```

And lastly, you can add multiple ranges to `OMaths` object, and use `BuildUp` to build all at once.

Try this code and combine it with your solution:

```
var oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;                       
var oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();
var math = oDoc.OMaths;

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    oDoc.Paragraphs.Add();
    var para = oDoc.Paragraphs[i];
    var paraRange = para.Range;
    paraRange.Text = "x^2 + " + i + " = y";
    math.Add(paraRange);
}
math.BuildUp();
oWord.Quit();
```

/edit

As @JLA discovered, more complex scenerios, like `\mapsto` or `⟼` does not work.

**First attempt: word macro**

Word under the scenes manages to convert it so in developer ribbon tab i have enebled recording, just to notice that when recording is enabled it doesn't work anymore...

**Second attempt: Converting LaTeX to MathML**

From question [Tools for converting LaTeX equations to Content MathML or OpenMath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3599602/1498401) I got [SnuggleTeX](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex) with [live demo converting to MathML](http://www2.ph.ed.ac.uk/snuggletex/MathInputDemo) but it only works for very simple scenarios like:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac></math>
```

Code for adding to Word:

```
Clipboard.SetText("<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\"><mrow><mn>1</mn><mn>x</mn></mrow></math>", TextDataFormat.Text);
```

**Third attempt: convert it yourself**

Change all your special names that does not work with `OMath` to UTF-16 chars. For example:

```
\mapsto = \u27FC
```

Code for Word:

```
paraRange.Text = "x^2 + "+ i + '\u27FC' +" y";
```

Comment: Ok, this answer is perfect because you made me understand what I didn't get through msdn documentation :  

- A Word equation is not much as a simple Paragraph.Range that you build up.  

- You can identify a Paragraph.Range as an equation by adding it to the Word.Document "collection" of it's kind named "OMaths" and this way, build all your equations only once !

Comment: glad to help, if it resolved your issue please mark as answered, and if you think it's useful - vote up!

Comment: As I'm new my upvote is note marked :/ I have another question also about equation on Word => how to build up the special signs like "\mapsto" ? (for example : "f:x \mapsto 3/2 ", 3/2 is built but not \mapsto)

Answer (score 2):

To anyone searching answers on that lib, as the msdn documentation is not that friendly, I made a quick documentation (PDF) on what I understood (it's in french but I'm confident you will probably manage to understand the code parts ;) )

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BybogIUkJwCfU2kzU3E4cE1HX2c/view?usp=sharing